# What is the default encoding mechanism for C# streams?

Tags: c#

Is UTF-8 the default encoding scheme?

Comment: it depends. what stream are you using?

Comment: The question is not answerable as posed. Stream is an abstract class that performs byte i/o.  There is no encoding done by Stream.  Your app writes bytes, or reads bytes, through the stream.  What you do with the bytes is up to you.  After reading a set of bytes, you may wish to convert the bytes to strings, using a specific text encoding. That is up to your app; it is not done by the stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams doesn't use any encodings, as Cheeso explained in the comment.

Related classes that do use an encoding, like `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, use UTF-8 as the default encoding.